# Как игнорировать, кнопку подписки на канал, по ссылке и запрещенному слову?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как игнорировать кнопку подписки, на канал и кнопку снять ограничения, если пользователь группы телеграм, опубликовал запрещенное слово или ссылку, чтобы кнопки не появлялись?

Вот кусок кода, в котором, 2 кнопки, канал и проверяет подписку, но как то, не правильно работает, если отправляю запрещенное слово, появляются 2 кнопки, а когда отправляю, например, любое слово, кнопки не появляются.

```html
if hasattr(message, 'text') and isinstance(text, str) and 'word' not in ['uonline_words']:
```

Этот кусок кода, удаляет запрещенные слова.

```html
      for word in uonline_words:
        if message.text is not None and word in message.text.lower():
```

Подскажите, чтобы и для ссылок, так же было, если участник группы, опубликовал ссылку и не подписан на канал, чтобы кнопки не появлялись.
Кусок кода, удаляет ссылки.

```html
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link", "mention", "text_mention"]:
```